# Possible to access clicked element from callback function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <a id="sub1">sub1</div>
    <a id="sub2">sub2</div>
</div>
<div id="other" style="display:none">
 some stuff    
</div>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$("div#main a").click(function () {
    $("#other").fadeIn(500,AlertSomething);
});

function AlertSomething()
{
     alert($(this).attr("id"));   
}
```

I would like to alert the ID of the anchor that was clicked from my call back function, but the alert always shows "other".  After reading this in the documentation:

> The callback is not sent any arguments, but this is set to the DOM
>   element being animated.

I understand why, but I'm curious if it would be possible to do what I want?

Fiddle available here:  http://jsfiddle.net/RxcRY/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply pass your `AlertSomething` method the ID.

```
$("div#main a").click(function () {
    $("#other").fadeIn(500, AlertSomething($(this).attr("id"));
});

function AlertSomething(theID)
{
    alert(theID);   
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxcRY/9/).

**Site Note:**

You're anchor tags are being closed with `</div>` instead of `</a>`. This will result in jQuery attaching to the click event of the first anchor, but not subsequent anchors. Once you fix your markup, jQuery will attach to each anchor within the div.

Comment: Are you sure you can pass arguments?  I thought that they were saying you can't: `The callback is not sent any arguments...`

Answer (score 2):

the .click() function passes in the event object representing the click. part of this object is the target of the click, so simply pass on the event handler to your function.

```
$("div#main a").click(function (e) {
    $("#other").fadeIn(500,AlertSomething(e.target));
});

function AlertSomething(obj) {
   alert($(obj).attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: I'm too used to mootools where most everything is wrapped in a moo object for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("div#main a").click(function (e) {
    $("#other").fadeIn(500,AlertSomething(e));
});

function AlertSomething(e)
{
    console.log(e); // this will show you the "click" event. 
    //alert($(this).attr("id"));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#main a").click(function () {
   var clickedElement = $(this);
    $("#other").fadeIn(500, function() { AlertSomething(clickedElement); });
});

function AlertSomething(el)
{
     alert($(el).attr("id"));   
}
```

this can be helpful